# How to get the count of values greater than zero from a subset of an array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I want to get a data set with an array that saves the count of values greater than zero in a subset of an array.

My code:

```
%Macro Test(input_array, window);
    array initial{*} &input_array;
    array position[&window];
    array cumulative[&window];

    /* Fill array indicating position with value zero, previous value greater than zero */
    do i = 1 to dim(initial) - 1;
        if initial(i) gt 0 and initial(i+1) eq 0 then
            position(i) = i + 1;
    end;
    
    /* Fill array indicating the count of values greater than zero until the index in the position array*/
    %let j = 1;
    %do %while (&j lt &window);
        end_ = coalesce(of position&j - position&window);
    
        if not missing(end_) then do;
            gt_0_cnt = 0;
            do k = &j to end_ - 1;
                gt_0_cnt + ifn(initial(k) > 0,1,0);
            end;
            cumulative(end_ - 1) = gt_0_cnt;
        end;
        %let j = %eval(&j + end_);
    %end;

%Mend;

DATA HAVE;
    INPUT ID FM1-FM18;
    DATALINES;
A 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 0
B 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 1 2 0 0
;
RUN;

DATA WANT;
    SET HAVE;

    %Test(FM: 18);
RUN;
```

The output I need:

[image: Output]

But I have a problem when trying to evaluate this expression

```
%let j = %eval(&j + end_)
```

I get the messaje *ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was:
1 + end_*

I don't know of any other way to get the desired result.

If someone can help me I will be grateful.

Comment: The letters END_ do not represent a number to the macro processor.  What is the purpose of the macro code?  Write out what SAS code you want the macro code the generate and get that to work first before trying to use macro logic to generate it.

Comment: Should your %DO J loop just be a normal DO J loop intead?  Then you could actually test the value of the variable END_.

Comment: Can you restructure your data? If you had a long formatted data it would be very easy....

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you need the macro language for this.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array fm fm:;
  array cum cum_1-cum_18;
  do _i = 1 to dim(fm);
    if fm[_i] eq 0 then call missing(cum[_i]);
    else do;
        do count = 1 by 1 until (fm[_i+count] eq 0 or (count+_i eq dim(fm)));
            
        end;
        put _i= count=;
        cum[_i+count-1] = count;  
        _i = _i + count - 1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Obviously you can specify the 18 max on the `cum` array through a macro parameter, or what the variable names are, but all of the stuff you're doing is perfectly doable through the data step language or simple macro variable parameters.